# Hit deadlock when Select channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Server1(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(2*time.Second)
    ch <- "from Server-1"
}

func Server2(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
    ch <- "from Server-2"
}

func main() {
    input1 := make(chan string)
    input2 := make(chan string)
    
    go Server1(input1)
    go Server2(input2)
    
    for {
        select {
            case s1 := <- input1:
                fmt.Printf(s1 + "\n")
            case s2 := <- input2:
                fmt.Printf(s2 + "\n")   
        }
    }
}
```

Ran the above code, get errors as following

```
from Server-1
from Server-2
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

In this channel select, we have two threads running with different timer interval, Why is it a deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You launch 2 goroutines that only send a single value on their channel, then they will terminate, so the `main` function will be left there hanging alone. That's why the deadlock.

If you modify `Server1()` and `Server2()` to send values endlessly, it won't be a deadlock:

```
func Server1(ch chan string) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        ch <- "from Server-1"
    }
}

func Server2(ch chan string) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        ch <- "from Server-2"
    }
}
```